# How to convert xhr request to angular $http request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to load image via `ajax`by the following code which is already Working . I am trying to convert it into angular `$http` and it doesn't work.

**Plain ajax code**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', attr.imageUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    element[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
};

xhr.send();
```

**Angular Code**

```
$http.get(attr.imageUrl, {}, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
.success(function(response) {
    var file = new Blob([response]);
    element[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

Comment: What does your `response` object look like ? Angular puts the response in `response.data`

Comment: this article might be helpful - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
$http.get({ url: attr.imageUrl, responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
.success(function(response) {
    var file = new Blob([response]);
    element[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

Or:

```
$http.get(attr.imageUrl, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
.success(function(response) {
    var file = new Blob([response]);
    element[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

Comment: first is `$http.get(config)` second is `$http.get(url, config)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $http.get(attr.imageUrl, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .then(function(response) {
    var file = new Blob([response]);
    element[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  });
```

Comment: The difference is your params, you have this: `$http.get(attr.imageUrl, {}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})`, you don't need the second param `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
$http.get(attr.imageUrl, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .then(function(response) {
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {
                    type: 'application/octet-binary'
                });
    element[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  });
```